# Combining two queries with different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite3 to get results for two queries with different WHERE conditions from the same table.  I can get the queries to work independently, but haven't been able to combine them.

Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'With Survivors', Day FROM crashes 
WHERE Fatalities < Aboard Group BY DIndex
```

Results:

```
    With Survivors  Day
0   231             Monday
1   262             Tuesday
2   243             Wednesday
3   271             Thursday
4   255             Friday
5   254             Saturday
6   216             Sunday
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS 'Total Crashes', Day FROM crashes GROUP BY DIndex
```

Results:

```
    Total Crashes  Day
0   713            Monday
1   796            Tuesday
2   796            Wednesday
3   818            Thursday
4   797            Friday
5   741            Saturday
6   607            Sunday
```

I would like to combine them so that I can get the following:

```
    With Survivors  Total Crashes   Day
0   231             713             Monday
1   262             796             Tuesday
2   243             796             Wednesday
3   271             818             Thursday
4   255             797             Friday
5   254             741             Saturday
6   216             607             Sunday
```

I'm fairly new to SQL, so while I've tried searching for answers, I'm not even sure I'm putting the right query into my search engine.

Comment: what is the structure of your "crashes" table maybe you can pick multiple columns you want to return

Comment: why not join these two queries . Consider first query As view 1 , second as view 2 and then join on day name columns. e.g: say `Select A.'With Survivors', B.'Total Crashes' , A.Day from A join B on Day` where A is query 1, B is query 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite supports the CASE expression so something like this should work

```
SELECT 
   Sum( Case WHEN Fatalities < Aboard THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) AS 'With Survivors',
   Count(*) AS 'Total Crashes', 
   Day 
FROM crashes 
GROUP BY DIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use UNION to combine two SELECT statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'With Survivors', Day FROM crashes 
WHERE Fatalities < Aboard Group BY DIndex
UNION
SELECT Count(*) AS 'Total Crashes', Day FROM crashes GROUP BY DIndex;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't give me quite what I was looking for.  It ended up with the following results:``` With Survivors Day
0 216 Sunday
1 231 Monday
2 243 Wednesday
3 254 Saturday
4 255 Friday
5 262 Tuesday
6 271 Thursday
7 607 Sunday
8 713 Monday
9 741 Saturday
10 796 Tuesday
11 796 Wednesday
12 797 Friday
13 818 Thursday```